# What's the meaning of '()' in OCaml?

Tags: function, ocaml

In [the book Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/command-line-parsing.html#adding-labeled-flags-to-the-command-line), I find this code:

```
let command = 
  Command.basic
    ~summary:"Generate an MD5 hash of the input data" 
    Command.Spec.(
      empty
      ...
      +> anon (maybe_with_default "-" ("filename" %: file))
    )
    (fun use_string trial filename () ->
```

I see `()` in the last line (`fun use_string trial filename ()`).

Also from [Print a List in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134929/print-a-list-in-ocaml), I also see `()` in the first match.

```
let rec print_list = function 
[] -> ()
| e::l -> print_int e ; print_string " " ; print_list l
```

Then, what's the meaning of `()` in both cases? How does the lambda expression (`fun`) have `()` in its parameter list?

Comment: The closest analogy is the `void` type in C. But there's a subtle but important type theoretic difference.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3494668/1959808

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a nullary constructor, the sole constructor of [type `unit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). The convention is to use this constructor to indicate "no particular value", which is common when working with effectful code.

Returning `()` is the ML way to return nothing.

When appearing in an argument list it is matched, just like any other constructor. This is a way to indicate there is no value for an argument. It's necessary to do this in ML because all functions are unary. You can't have a function with zero arguments, so instead you pass an argument containing no information, which is `()`.

Comment: Not only all ML functions take exactly one argument, but they also return exactly one result. So `()` is also what a function returns when it doesn't have any value it wants to return. Both are typical of effectful code: if `f` is pure and takes no arguments, there is no reason not to make it a constant instead, and if it has no result to return, that means that it is interesting for its effects.

Comment: The unit type is also useful in polymorphic data structures, such as a hash table used as just a set of keys (`(string, unit) Hashtbl.t`).